# Can we access source code of the repository files within the Sonar Qube plugin?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I am working on a SonarQube plugin. As part of that, I need to access the source code for a specific project in SonarQube.

I am newbie in SonarQube. Is there any way we can do this?

PS: I tried searching documentation. But I didnt find any concrete steps.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Gowtham

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube provides an option for this using API: https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/sources